# Intervalo de datas em uma Collection Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collection

Tenho a seguinte `collection` Laravel

```
"data": [
         {
            "id": 1,
            "uuid": "5f948b5b-b8c1-45de-9d8b-b8c272df53ad",
            "issue_date": "2009-01-02",
            "issue_date_end": "2012-03-12",
        },
    ]
```

Como posso fazer uma comparação de intervalo baseado na chave `issue_date` e `issue_date_end`?
Exemplo: Gostaria de testar se a data ***2010-09-06*** está entre a `issue_date` e `issue_date_end`.

Tenho feito da seguinte forma:

```
$query->collection= $query->collection->filter(function ($row) use ($request) {
    return collect($row['issue_date'])->where('issue_date','<=', 2010-09-06)
                                      ->where('issue_date_end','>=', 2010-09-06);
});
```

Mas isso parece não funcionar,tentei tambem com o `whereBetween`, mas não funcionou com Strings.

Comment: tu colocou duas clausulas `where`. Em `sql` isso não é possível. Se quer utilizar mais condições nas clausuras where deve usar `OR` ou `AND`.

Comment: Sim,mas isso não e `SQL`

Comment: O caminho é usar between. O problema é que você está tratando `2010-09-06` numericamente (calculando) em vez de usar uma string ou data, efetivamente mandando o valor `1995` para a query. Fundamental nesses casos um [mcve] do problema.

Comment: @Danizavtz esta enganado, o where() no Eloquent não é a mesma coisa que o WHERE da sintaxe SQL, no eloquent existe o where(), whereIn(), whereColumn(), whereTime(), etc. Esses **métodos** adicionam "instruções ao "QueryBuilder", para no "final" gerar a query de verdade, é um ORM então.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```php
$query->collection = $query->collection->filter(function ($row) use ($request) {
    return strtotime($row->issue_date) <= strtotime("2010-09-06") &&
        strtotime($row->issue_date_end) >= strtotime("2010-09-06");
});
```